# Laravel query result in complex scenario

Tags: laravel

```php
$salestage = Lead::where('stage_id', '5')->get();

$task_dues_today = \App\Models\Task::whereDate(
                       'task_due_date', '=', \Carbon\Carbon::today()
                   )->get();
```

Lead Table: id, leadname, stage_id.
task table: id, lead_id, task.

I have two tables leads and tasks, table tasks has a lead_id, now i want the query results to show all the tasks that ends today of the leads that belogs to stage 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whereHas()` Eloquent function to query from relationships.

```php
$tasksDueToday = Task::whereHas('leads', function($leadQuery) {
                     $leadQuery->where('lead_id', 5);
                 })
                 ->whereDate('task_due_date', now())
                 ->get();
```

**NOTE**

You must have defined `leads()` relationship on `Task` model.

```php
public function leads()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Lead::class);
}
```